# Lilliefors test is not working in python statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to implement lilliefors normality test using python statsmodels and I receive error messages.

I receive this error when I run the code:
ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import lilliefors

count=1000 

mu=1.5
sigma=2
x=np.random.normal(mu,sigma,count)   

print(lilliefors(x, dist='norm', pvalmethod='table'))
```

When I ommit pvalmethod I receive the following error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pval' referenced before assignment

When I use

```py
print(lilliefors(x, dist='norm', pvalmethod='approx'))
```

the code gives sometimes (approximately at 1 in 10 runs) results.
However (probably due to the use of "random") the same code often returns me the message

raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation"

Finally, when I use a smaller sample of values (e.g. count=100) the code runs and give me results for all pvalmethod cases.

What am I missing?

Comment: this is most likely https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5333 fixed for the next release

Comment: I am using statsmodels version 0.10.1